# Spark: How to merge two similar columns from two DataFrames in one column by doing join?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have SQL table that I have to update by using data from with table.

For this purpose, I calculate DataFrame.

I have two DataFrame: that I calculate and that I get from database.

```
val myDF = spark.read.<todo something>.load()

val dbDF = spark.read.format("jdbc").<...>.load()
```

Finally, both DataFrame have the same structure.

For example:

myDF

| key | column |
| --- | --- |
| key1 | 1 |
| key2 | 2 |
| key3 | 3 |

dbDF

| key | column |
| --- | --- |
| key1 | 5 |
| key2 | 5 |
| key3 | 5 |

I need to get new DF that will have only one column with name Column.

newDF

| key | column |
| --- | --- |
| key1 | 6 |
| key2 | 7 |
| key3 | 8 |

For this purpose, I do next actions:

```
myDF
  .as("left")
  .join(dbDF.as("right"), "key")
  .withColumn("column_temp", $"left.column" + $"right.column")
  .drop($"left.column")
  .drop(s"right.column")
  .withColumnRenamed("column_temp", "column")
```

I have to do these actions for each column that I have to calculate.

In other words, my joins don't assume adding new columns. I have to merge similar columns into one column.

I can calculate new column by sum two column, or a can just choose not null column from two given columns, like that:

```
myDF
  .as("left")
  .join(dbDF.as("right"), $"key", "outer")
  .withColumn("column_temp", coalesce($"left.column", $"right.column"))
  .drop($"left.column")
  .drop(s"right.column")
  .withColumnRenamed("column_temp", "column")
```

And when my DataFrame have many columns and only 1 or 2 key columns, I have to repeat above actions for each column.

**My question is:**

Is there more effective way to do what I do? Or do I do it right?

Answer (score 0):

```
    myDF.join(dbDF,myDF.col("key").equalTo(dbDF.col("key")))
            .select(myDF.col("key"),myDF.col("column").plus(dbDF.col("column")).alias("column");
```

Can you try this? It is an inner join so only those rows in the left table that have a match in the right are selected. Is that your case?

Comment: But you calculate value of "column" column by using values of "key" columns.

Comment: sorry, just updated answer.

Comment: It looks interesting, i try this version